# Can I display mysql query as a view in Django admin?

Tags: mysql, django, admin

I have this query

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE t.*,log.* 
FROM outofoffice_agent t 
join ( SELECT lo.status,lo.agent_id
        FROM outofoffice_agentavailabilitylog lo 
        WHERE lo.timestamp in (SELECT max(l.timestamp) 
        FROM outofoffice_agentavailabilitylog l
        group by l.agent_id) ) as log ON t.id=log.agent_id
```

and I want to display as a grid in admin panel like any other modal admin, is that possible ?

Comment: Have you tried rewriting the admin [get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method?

Comment: no, actually, will look into it, thanks